# Flow, send e-mail just once

Tags: outgoing-email, flow

i have a flow (when item is created or modified), that takes trigger for SHP List. I need to send email but ONLY ONCE after set collum "bank" as "yes"... IF "bank" = yes
THEN send e-mail.

Now, if the user modified the item e.g. in 10 days later (some detail) the mail is send again, and i dont want it :-)
Please how to set it to send only on first modify

Thanks,

Milan

Answer (score 3):

You would need to make a "shadow" field which you compare to see if an email has been sent already.

So create a boolean field called MailSent, default it to "No". Now change your flow to make it only send mail if the field is equal to "No" - and when that is the case set the field value to "Yes".